# Send E-Mail in HTML with an Appointment/Event

Tags: html, email, outlook, icalendar

As mentioned in the title, I just need  to send an e-mail with both HTML and ICS, and the client side I'm using MS Outlook, I need to add this event or appointment to the MS Outlook calender automatically.
I've already develop my server side program to sent e-mail with event/appointment.
It'll show in MS Out look like this.
[image: E-Mail on Outlook]

You can see the Message tab is empty. When I clicked on the *.ics tab it says `This file cannot be previewed because there is previewer installed for it.` Just ignore it, and when I double clicked on the *.ics tab it'll pop-up the Outlook Calender with new appointment.

And here is the code of my ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20080514T212222Z
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20141231T160000Z
DTSTAMP:20141223T101200Z
DTSTART:20141231T151500Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20141217T212222Z
LOCATION:Meeting Room 21
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test Link to Add to Calendar
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000002B4203E7B5C80100000000000000001000000044A68E0A5C6AF14C9AAAA609FA417940
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.00.0681.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDA
```

Well I need to do is,

1. Display some HTML type content  in the "Message" tab.
2. Add this eventwhich is on the ics to Outlook calender automatically,
   When user open the email it just add to the calender.

The header of the shown message is,

```
Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;
Content-Type: text/calendar;charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Do I have to change the header and the ics file? Or how can I do such a thing? Couldn't find much help from the Microsoft support or the Documentation of [iCalender](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt)

Comment: Did you try to create an appointment in Outlook and then save it as .ics file? Do you get the same results with an auto-generated .ics files?

Comment: Yes.. I've already tried. I think there is nothing wrong in .ics file..? I can show some contents in the event body.. which is in Rich Text Format...just adding the content into the <body> tag in the ics file. But I need to add some content to the message.

Comment: Do you get the same results with an auto-generated .ics files?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yeap... I've got the same results. My auto-generated .ics files are working fine, they just add the event to the calender. What I'm asking is how to put some HTML content inside the message. Every .ics files opens with empty message. Thanks for your response....

Comment: So, you may customize the appointment's body (which is auto-generated) and see what should be done and how.